# Identify and isolate hebrew word with regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, right-to-left, hebrew

I need to parse a hebrew sentence to identify and isolate (so I can wrap them up with 'span' tags) every word in it. 
I'm first trying without punctuation by identifying the non spaces chars from the spaces chars but still doesn't work:

```
var regex = /(\s)*(\S)+(\s)*/g;
```

any idea?
thanks

edit: I have already a regular expression that does the job in english, I'm putting it in case it can help to understand what I want to achieve:

```
var regExp = /\b([^\s']+)\b/g,
```

edit2: Adding code example

```
var regex = /(\s)*(\S)+(\s)*/g;
var sentence = "שלום מה קורה מהיום";
sentence.replace(regex, function(match, p1, p2, p3){console.log('"' + match + '"', '"' + p1 + '"', '"' + p2 + '"', '"' + p3 + '"');});


// result
"שלום " "undefined" "ם" " " VM1494:2
"מה " "undefined" "ה" " " VM1494:2
"קורה " "undefined" "ה" " " VM1494:2
"היום" "undefined" "ם" "undefined" VM1494:2
"undefinedundefinedundefinedundefined"
```

edit3: I need to be able to reassemble the sentence with the same punctuation at the end.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work". Doesn't match your source string? Doesn't capture what you want? Please provide example strings that it should match, as well as those that it shoudln't.

Comment: @David-SkyMesh: edited my post with example

Comment: You've got a variable number of matches. Try changing `(\s)*` to `(\s*)` both times, and change `(\S)+` to `(\S+)`.

Comment: You want to capture words without spaces and punctuations, right?

Comment: @lior yes that's exactly what I'm trying to do. So then I can put each word inside markup

Comment: @David-SkyMesh I did as you said, but in my 'p2' variable I'm still getting a space
"שלום " "" "ם" " " 
"מה " "" "ה" " " 
"קורה " "" "ה" " " 
"היום" "" "ם" ""

Comment: If your regexp is now `(\s*)(\S+)(\s*)` and that's not matching, then you'd have to think that somehow the character class `\S` isn't matching hebrew characters correctly (unlikely).

Comment: I'm not familiar with hebrew, would you please define correct words and boundaries in your sample? Because your pattern split sentence by space perfectly. I want to understand the question.

Comment: @JonathanBensaid What is the expected result? I mean, if you want to wrap them and reassemble them as well. What do you want to have at the end of the process? An array with just the words or also punctuations?

Comment: @Lior my goal is to recognize words. I have a sentence and I want let say to give the user the possibility to select a word just by clicking on it. That's why I need first to parse the sentence, find all the words and wrap them with tags. Then I can do my business logic

Comment: @JonathanBensaid I updated my answer, give it a try...

Comment: @Mehdi with a sentence like the following (see spaces and ',') 
"שלום, מה קורה היום" we should have the following:
<span>היום</span><span>קורה</span><span>מה</span>,<span>שלום</span>
Note that the ',' is outside of the 'span'. And everything should be read from RTL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as you might know Hebrew in the web is a bitch.
Try using this regex:

```
[\s]*(\S)+[\s]*
```

example:

```
var words = sentence.match(/[\s]*(\S)+[\s]*/g);
```

It does leave in the trailing spaces to clear them up you could do something of this sort:

```
words = words.join().split(" ")
```

I'm trying out some other regex variations to try and circumvent the join-split hack, I'll update if I find anything.

Also, you could go the "replace" way and do:

```
var words = sentence.replace(/[#`~?!#\$%\.;:,]*/g, "").split(" ")
```

Just make sure to add any punctuation that might be used.

Then to get a new HTML string with the words wrapped with a span tag you can do this:

Let's say that:

```
var sentence = "?שלום, מה קורה מהיום"
var words = sentence.replace(/[#`~?!#\$%\.;:,]*/g, "").split(" ")
```

Then:

```
var newSentence = encodeURI(sentence)
words.forEach(function(word){
   word = encodeURI(word)
   newSentence = newSentence.replace(word, "<span>" + word + "</span>")
})
newSentence = decodeURI(newSentence);
```

`newSentence` will have your words wrapped with a span tag while leaving in the punctuations:

Comment: You're welcome, Glad to have helped. If you could vote up my answer and mark it as the solution I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I've marked it as the solution, but not able to vote up since I'm new on stack overflow. I need 15 and I have only 8 reputation points...

Comment: No worries, you can always came back when you do ;)

Answer (score 1):

try unicode between chars regexp match type of hebrew range

```
"בדיקה, להלהלה".match(/[\u0590-\u05F4\uFB00-\uFB4F]+/g)
```

by punctuation (simple):

```
".בדיק'ה, להלהל\"ה".match(/[^,.]+/g)
```

regexp for all puntuation:

```
"aa bb cc.בדיק'ה, להלהל\"ה .test'da, te\"xt".replace(/[\-=_!"#%&'*{},.\/:;?\(\)\[\]@\\$\^*+<>~`\u00a1\u00a7\u00b6\u00b7\u00bf\u037e\u0387\u055a-\u055f\u0589\u05c0\u05c3\u05c6\u05f3\u05f4\u0609\u060a\u060c\u060d\u061b\u061e\u061f\u066a-\u066d\u06d4\u0700-\u070d\u07f7-\u07f9\u0830-\u083e\u085e\u0964\u0965\u0970\u0af0\u0df4\u0e4f\u0e5a\u0e5b\u0f04-\u0f12\u0f14\u0f85\u0fd0-\u0fd4\u0fd9\u0fda\u104a-\u104f\u10fb\u1360-\u1368\u166d\u166e\u16eb-\u16ed\u1735\u1736\u17d4-\u17d6\u17d8-\u17da\u1800-\u1805\u1807-\u180a\u1944\u1945\u1a1e\u1a1f\u1aa0-\u1aa6\u1aa8-\u1aad\u1b5a-\u1b60\u1bfc-\u1bff\u1c3b-\u1c3f\u1c7e\u1c7f\u1cc0-\u1cc7\u1cd3\u2016\u2017\u2020-\u2027\u2030-\u2038\u203b-\u203e\u2041-\u2043\u2047-\u2051\u2053\u2055-\u205e\u2cf9-\u2cfc\u2cfe\u2cff\u2d70\u2e00\u2e01\u2e06-\u2e08\u2e0b\u2e0e-\u2e16\u2e18\u2e19\u2e1b\u2e1e\u2e1f\u2e2a-\u2e2e\u2e30-\u2e39\u3001-\u3003\u303d\u30fb\ua4fe\ua4ff\ua60d-\ua60f\ua673\ua67e\ua6f2-\ua6f7\ua874-\ua877\ua8ce\ua8cf\ua8f8-\ua8fa\ua92e\ua92f\ua95f\ua9c1-\ua9cd\ua9de\ua9df\uaa5c-\uaa5f\uaade\uaadf\uaaf0\uaaf1\uabeb\ufe10-\ufe16\ufe19\ufe30\ufe45\ufe46\ufe49-\ufe4c\ufe50-\ufe52\ufe54-\ufe57\ufe5f-\ufe61\ufe68\ufe6a\ufe6b\uff01-\uff03\uff05-\uff07\uff0a\uff0c\uff0e\uff0f\uff1a\uff1b\uff1f\uff20\uff3c\uff61\uff64\uff65]+/g," ")
```

actually, there are many abbreviations in Hebrew probably to include them too

```
".בדיק'ה, להלהל\"ה".match(/[\u0590-\u05F4\uFB00-\uFB4F][\u0590-\u05F4\uFB00-\uFB4F'"]*/g)
(2) ["בדיק'ה", "להלהל"ה"]
```

original phrase

```
"שלום, מה קורה מהיום".match(/[\u0590-\u05F4\uFB00-\uFB4F][\u0590-\u05F4\uFB00-\uFB4F'"]*/g)
(4) ["שלום", "מה", "קורה", "מהיום"]
```

with english

```
 "aa bb cc.בדיק'ה, להלהל\"ה .test'da, te\"xt".match(/[\u0590-\u05F4\uFB00-\uFB4F][\u0590-\u05F4\uFB00-\uFB4F'"]*/g)
(2) ["בדיק'ה", "להלהל"ה"]
```

maybe add English too (I decided there are no Hebrew style abbreviations in English)

```
"aa bb cc.בדיק'ה, להלהל\"ה .test'da, te\"xt".match(/[\u0590-\u05F4\uFB00-\uFB4F][\u0590-\u05F4\uFB00-\uFB4F'"]*|[a-zA-Z']+/g)
(8) ["aa", "bb", "cc", "בדיק'ה", "להלהל"ה", "test'da", "te", "xt"]
```

Answer (score 0):

i would do it this way:

```
yourString.split(' ').map(function(e){ return "<span>"+e+"</span>"; }).join('');
```

and make sure to add `style="direction:rtl;` to the wrapper element to handle punctuation.

Comment: What about if the string contains multiple spaces or punctuations?
Also, just a note, the question wasn't about the html wrapping implementation but about the problematic regex...

Comment: Lior, you spot the big problem, strings with multiple punctuation. That is where the difficulty lies

Comment: @JonathanBensaid can you answer my question I asked in a comment above, about the result format you're expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Just omit the matching groups from spaces.

```
var regex = /[\s,]*([^\s,]+)[\s,]*/g;

var sentence = "שלום, מה קורה מהיום";

var text = sentence.replace(regex, '<span>$1</span>');

console.log(text);  

// <span>שלום</span><span>מה</span><span>קורה</span><span>מהיום</span>
```

Comment: Thanks Ilan but, I need to keep to reassemble the sentence with same punctuation after wrapping.
So split won't help here.
I forgot to mention it in my question, editing right now

Comment: I updated my answer. I hope I understand what you need.

Comment: I tried with your code, it works but takes also punctuation with the word.
"<span>שלום,</span><span>מה</span><span>קורה</span><span>היום</span>"

Comment: Maybe we can improve your regex like this:

    regex = /[\s,]*([^\s,]+)[\s,]*/g;
    sentence = "שלום,  מה קורה היום";
    text = sentence.replace(regex, '<span>$1</span>')
    "<span>שלום</span><span>מה</span><span>קורה</span><span>היום</span>"