# PHP regex is too greedy when trying to fetch Foreign chars

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

It's seems like a newbie question,
But I am fighting with this super simple regex for too long,
Googled it and didn't find the answer.

I am lookin to fetch Hebrew chars from within HTML.
this is my code sample, the weird chars are in Hebrew.

```
<DIV>
<span>
שלום</span> inside a span
מה<b> קורה</b> is "whats up"
Peace is also שלומות in Hebrew
</div>
```

I want the result to be only the Hebrew words not include anything:

> שלום
>   מה
>   קורה
>   שלומות

I have tried the next regex's
`preg_match("/([\p{Hebrew}].*)/u", $input_line, $output_array);`

but then its get super greedy

```
שלום</span> inside a span    
מה<b> קורה</b> is "whats up"  
שלומות in Hebrew
```

while if I am trying the non greedy:

```
preg_match("/([\p{Hebrew}].*?)/u", $input_line, $output_array);
```

I am getting only the first Hebrew char in each line:

```
ש
מ
ש
```

I am sure this is a simple flag but I can't find it :-(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Identify and isolate hebrew word with regexp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21215580/identify-and-isolate-hebrew-word-with-regexp)

Comment: The answer there is about JS, and anyway my question is about greediness of the regex in hebrew.

Comment: Try remove the dot.

Comment: @Daniel please remove your duplication warning, there is no duplication here, totally different question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've forgotten the quantifier and there're no needs for character class:

```
preg_match("/(\p{Hebrew}+)/u", $input_line, $output_array);
```